# LaTeX puts too much space next to integrals

Tags: latex, whitespace, integral

Integrals with limits take up width horizontally that includes their limits.  In other words, if you have an integral with large limits below (or above) the integral

```
\int\limits_{-\infty < x < c} (c - x) \ dP(x)
```

you are left with a large amount of space to the left and right of the integral before the integrand (c - x) starts.  This is sometimes desirable, but in my case it isn't, since I have a whole bunch of integrals like this all in the same expression.  Is there a way to make whatever is inside the integral snuggle up next to the integral sign, ignoring the width of the limit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\mathclap#1{\text{\hbox to 0pt{\hss$\mathsurround=0pt#1$\hss}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\int\limits_{\mathclap{-\infty < x < c}} (c - x) \ dP(x)
\]
\end{document}
```

More about such tricks is given in [this article](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

It is possible with less effort:

```
\int\!\!\!{olution}
```

`\!` is a negative space. However, when a lot of formulas have to be altered, the previously posted answers may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The `mathtools` package contains a definition for `\mathclap`, and also a command `\smashoperator` that is a bit more convenient:

```
\smashoperator{\int_{\infty < x < c}} (c - x) \, dP(x)
```